# Java Swing Applet redrawing garbage after mouse event

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet

I'm having issues with my Java Swing Applet. I recently reformatted my computer and reinstalled Eclipse to continue work on my application but I'm having an issue when the screen redraws. Up until now the code has worked 100% (No issues) so I'm certain its an issue with my configuration settings.

The Applet will load fine but after any form of event the screen redraws to something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sX14.png

I'm using Eclipse Helios with pretty much a bare bones installation. Its configured to use jre6 but I have no idea why this occurs.

****Please also note that if I embed the applet in an html file it works fine! I however need the applet to run for various debug features I need while working on the AI

Comment: You might show what it's _supposed_ to look like, too. Also, verify starting on [the event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: How it is supposed to look: http://i.imgur.com/gegqt.png -- When the game loads this is fine. After the 1st mouse event it redraws to the garbage I included above. The game is playable but obviously difficult due to the redraw issue. Clicking on the grid generates the proper events and execution. Again the drawing is the ONLY thing that has messed up and this code worked fine prior to my reinstall (Nothing changed in the code afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you are constructing the GUI on the [*event dispatch thread*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). This is required for Swing applets, too.

Comment: Adding a test for javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() returns true every time during the GUI's construction. I understand I'm probably not giving you enough information to properly work with the problem but I'm not sure what relevent information you require, please ask any questions you have and I'll provide as much information as possible.

Comment: It appears that the switch from 5 to 6 may have exposed an existing synchronization problem. Unfortunately, `isEventDispatchThread()` is a necessary but not sufficient condition. You still have to look for post-construction GUI method calls that are _not_ running on the EDT. Any chance you also changed video cards? Different timing on various cards is one way to expose such problems.

Comment: Same video card (working on a laptop) but upgraded to a SSD during the reformat

Comment: Playing around with some concurrency items it appears as though you are right. Time to buckle down and dig through my partner's UI code :(

Comment: Don't be too hard on your partner; such anomalies are frequently latent and notoriously protean. Kudos for perseverance.

Comment: No, we're good friends and I'm not an idiot. This was a university project class which we took on. I recently updated it with a very advanced AI feature that I want to publish to my blog (the AI is actually quite useful for a number of applications) and needed to add some stuff to make it more presentable when I discovered the bug. I just want to thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Excellent; I'd welcome a ping if you reference the article when published.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are missing a super,paintComponent(g) somewhere when you do custom painting.

Comment: The code is fine. The application worked 100% prior to my reformat and still works 100% when embedded in an html page. The only difference I can see with my environment is I *believe* I was in JRE5 prior to reformat and am now using JRE6.